# I got error from ArrayList

Tags: java

I used it before on JDK 1.7. It was OK. After move it to new laptop with JDK 1.8. I got Syntax error from "ArrayList array = new ArrayList()" line. Someone know what happen it in here.

Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  FileWriter.java

```
    public static String[] fileToArray(String filename) throws IOException
        {
            FileReader file = new FileReader();
  error >>  ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line;

            file.open(filename);

            while((line = file.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.length() > 0)
                    array.add(line);
            }

            return (String[])array.toArray(new String[array.size()]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you compiling you code? Is it in Eclipse?

Comment: ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @user3076246 No, that's not the problem, the code is fine.

Comment: Somehow the IDE assumes the source code is below 1.5. My guess: you are using eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using Eclipse. Set the Source Code Level to 1.7.

Check what is under `Preferences > Java > Compiler >  JDK Compliance`. You should be able to set to `1.7`.

Comment: Java 8 isn't supported by default in Eclipse Kepler or prior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could kindly let me know where I can update the setting?

Comment: If you go to that option, you may see that there's no Java 8 support unless you're working with Eclipse Luna. And if you post the source code level to Java 6 or 7, Eclipse will complain that you don't have that version of Java installed/configured.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP's code contains no JDK8 specific syntax, so any JDK5+ compiler should be able to compile his code. Of course, he cannot use lambda, etc. that is JDK8 specific.

Comment: @GaborSch if you read my last comment, you may see that Eclipse won't support such java version because the Java compiler used is not Java 6 nor 7. It happened to me months ago.

Comment: Thank you! The default value was 1.6. So, I changed 1.7 then the error is gone. The eclipse may not support 1.8 yet.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP does not need JDK8 support. He only wants the backward compatibility to JDK7.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you work with Eclipse IDE and the version you use doesn't support Java 8. If so, the problem **is not in the code itself, but in the IDE**. When you use JDK 8 as default, Eclipse won't recognize it and it will set the source code level to 1.4 by default, despite if your code compiles for another version of Java. It is a nasty problem when dealing with Eclipse and JDK 8.

If you want to use Java 8, then move to Eclipse Luna or use Eclipse Kepler +  Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2. If you don't then just install JDK 7 and configure it for your Eclipse IDE.

More info:

- [Java™ 8 Support in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/)

Comment: I don't see any syntax here that's specific to Java 8...or 7, for that matter.

Comment: @Makoto answer edited to show what's the exact problem.

Comment: I think previous Kepler version was OK. I updated newer version as Luna and I setup jdk 8. do you know where I can change the source code level?

Comment: @duly right click in your project, Properties, Java Compiler, JDK Compliance.